# Pandas IF test to create new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

any idea how i can create a column C based on the test of 3 columns in a dataframe?

so far i have

```
df.loc[df['Negative'] > df['Neutral'] and df['Negative'] > df['Positive'], 
'C'] = 'Bad'
```

this gives me

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `()` and instead `and` use bitwise and - `&`:

```
df.loc[(df['Negative'] > df['Neutral']) & (df['Negative'] > df['Positive']), 'C'] = 'Bad'
```

Also if need `if-else` use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask  = (df['Negative'] > df['Neutral']) & (df['Negative'] > df['Positive'])
df['C'] = np.where(mask, 'Bad', 'Good')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using

```
df.C.where((df['Negative'] > df['Neutral'])& (df['Negative'] > df['Positive']), 'Bad')
```

And the whole if else statement with and

```
l=[]

for _,x in df.iterrows():

    if x['Negative'] > x['Neutral'] and x['Negative'] > x['Positive']:
        l.append('Bad')
    else :
        l.append('')

df.C=l
```